# Rewriting Subdomain to File, and then removing .htaccess authentication

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony1

I'm rewriting a domain for a Symfony 1.4 project.

My .htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "GH Auth"

<Files "*">
    require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "api.php">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Files>

<Files "apc.php">
    require user admin
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.domain\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  api.php [QSA,L]

# we skip all files with .something
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|png|gif|jpg)$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Going to domain.org/api.php/method correctly allows you to proceed without authentication.

However, going to api.domain.org/method seems to not see the  flag, and it still asks for authentication.

Any ideas? Maybe it's time to create two separate vhosts?

Comment: Have you tried using the `PT` flag in your rewrite rules? The "Pass Through" paired with the `L` tells apache to run the resulting URI back through the mapping engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to `apps/api/[your_module]`, you should see actions folder and template folders, then add a folder named `config` (if there isn't one) inside your module folder (parallel with actions & template folder), then add a file named `security.yml` inside config folder.

Add this following code in security.yml

```
all:
  is_secure: false
```

remember, because you just want to remove authentication process for a module,  the security.yml file you've edited config folder should be inside module folder, not in application folder. Because there is also config folder inside application folder.

Comment: sorry, this isn't about Symfony authentication; it's about HTTP basic authentication. please read my code sample again...